# Cannot run Sublime Text using ./subl

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor, sublimetext

I downloaded Sublime Text 4107 zip file. Unzipped it in a folder and tried running it using `./subl` command but no matter what I try it shows `

> “Sublime Text 15-33-10-536” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should
> move it to the Bin.

I have read every article available but no luck. Can anyone help me. If anybody want more information tell me comment section.
Also if I install Sublime using `.dmg` file and drag it into Applications folder it works fine.

Comment: What url did you down;load it from?

Comment: `https://www.sublimetext.com/download`

Comment: OK that produces a zip of an app bundle. There is no subl obvious so we need to kjnow the exact things you did so that we can replicate that.

Comment: I took the zip file and did `unzip file.zip -d SublimeText`. After the file was extracted I went to `SublimeText/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/` this bin folder has a subl file. Inside this `bin/` I did `./subl` which the produces the error.

Comment: If it works in /Applications then I think they have hardcoded that path so you have to use it there.

Comment: Move the app to /Applications to remove App Translocation as the problem, then launch the app from the GUI once so that macOS will verify it, then try subl again.  Additionally, make sure that you remove any quarantine app that may be there.